# C++ return vector

Tags: c++, data-structures, return, subset

I have a function that recives an array(int), and I have to return all the subsets with the sum 0. For exameple if my array list is (2,5,-3,-5,-2), my function has to return (2,-2),(5,-5),(5,-3,-2). How can I return this subsets, and how can I acces them furthe in the program(for example to display the 2'nd subset if does exist)?I mention that I don't need an alghoritm to find the subsets.If you would know how i could use vectorv[] it would be perfect

Comment: You either return the vector by value or pass it by reference and modify it in-place.

Comment: Also it is possible to return reference to vector, but it is a good idea not in all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you would know how i could use `vector v[]` it would be perfect

You cannot make a vector of arrays, but you can make a vector of vectors. That is the standard strategy in C++ when you need to make a container:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > make_sets(std::vector<int> data) {
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > res;
    std::vector<int> first;
    res.push_back(first);
    std::vector<int> second;
    res.push_back(second);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: How can i acces the further in the program.
I've tried something like this but it does not working: 
    vector < vector < int > >:: iterator it;
    vector <int>:: iterator it2;
    for(it=v.begin();it!=v.end();it++)
    {
        for(it2=it.begin();it2!=it.end;it++)
        {

        }
    }

Comment: @user2868657 since `it` is an iterator, pointer syntax needs to be used. Therefore, you should write `it->begin()`, `it->end()`, etc., rather than `it.begin()` and `it.end()`.

Answer (score 3):

You would return a vector of vectors:

```
template<size_t N>
std::vector<std::vector<int>> myFunc(const std::array<int, N>& arr)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> results;
    //... fill results
    return results;
}
```

Comment: How can i acces the further in the program. I've tried something like this but it does not working: vector < vector < int > >:: iterator it; vector <int>:: iterator it2; for(it=v.begin();it!=v.end();it++) { for(it2=it.begin();it2!=it.end;it++) { } } –

Comment: You have to keep the vector of vector in memory somewhere (it has to be in scope).  Other than that, it is just like accessing any other variable.